# Using GROUP BY/CASE with WHEN or IF

Tags: sql, if-statement, group-by, case, case-when

note: edited query below.

I am looking to segment a data set according to two criteria:

1. If a customer has **more or less than 4 txns** at a specific restaurant
2. If a customer has **more or less than 24 txns** at all the other restaurants in that data set.

I am using a conjunction of GROUP BY, CASE and WHEN or IF. I am not sure which approach is best, if either?

```
SELECT 
COUNT(Customer) AS number_of_customers, 
AVG (CASE WHEN ItemPrice LIKE '-%' THEN NULL
WHEN ItemPrice LIKE '0%' THEN NULL
ELSE CAST (ItemPrice AS FLOAT) END) AS avg_item_price, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(ReceiptIDDesc)) AS number_of_orders, 
SUM(CAST(ItemPrice AS FLOAT)) AS total_spend
FROM Tacos
WHERE NOT (PurchaseDate > '01/01/2016 12:00' OR '03/01/2016 12:00'< 
PurchaseDate)
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN (COUNT('MerchantFamily' = %TacoTruck%)> 2) AND COUNT('MerchantFamily' != %TacoTruck%) >24)
            THEN 'Fanatic'
        WHEN (COUNT('MerchantFamily' = %TacoTruck%)> 2) AND COUNT('MerchantFamily' != %TacoTruck%) <24)
            THEN 'Loyalist'
        WHEN (COUNT('MerchantFamily' = %TacoTruck%)< 2) AND COUNT('MerchantFamily' != %TacoTruck%) <24)
            THEN 'Seldom'
        ELSE
            'Potential'    
    END
```

OR

```
GROUP BY
    CASE
        IF(COUNT(IF( 'MerchantFamily' = 'TacoTruck', 1, 0 ) ) > 2, TRUE, FALSE)
        AND 
        IF(COUNT(IF( 'MerchantFamily' != 'TacoTruck',1, 0) ) < 24, TRUE, FALSE), 'Loyalist', NULL )
        IF(COUNT(IF( 'MerchantFamily' = 'TacoTruck', 1, 0 ) ) > 2, TRUE, FALSE) 
        AND
        IF(COUNT(IF( 'MerchantFamily' != 'TacoTruck', 1, 0 ) ) > 24, TRUE, FALSE), 'Fanatic', NULL) 
        IF(COUNT(IF( 'MerchantFamily' = 'TacoTruck', 1, 0 ) ) < 2, TRUE, FALSE) 
        AND
        IF(COUNT( IF( 'MerchantFamily' != 'TacoTruck', 1, 0 ) ) < 24, TRUE, FALSE), 'Seldom', NULL) 
    ELSE
        'Potential'
END
```

Comment: What is `%x%`? What implementation of SQL is this out of curiosity?

Comment: I'm seeing invalid SQL. `IFCOUNT` isn't a function in any SQL dialect I'm aware of, and the `=!` operator is the wrong way around.

Comment: Please provide sample data and the complete query, those pseudo code snippets don't help us answer. I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I was using x as a placeholder for the restaurant name, in combination with the like operator. Currently running SQuirreL SQL v.3.8.0.

Comment: IFCOUNT was a mistake on my part, was looking for a simple `COUNT` operator. Apologies for the incomplete formatting, I'm very new to SQL!

Comment: What server are you connecting to? Oracle / DB2 / SQL Sever 2012 / etc?

Comment: SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those approaches will work, you need to group first then consider the aggregated count values through a `having` clause, or as a nested subquery ("`derived table`").

A `case expression` only evaluates values on a per row basis, it does not scan multiple rows.